# fetch-запросы JS

Tags: javascript, fetch

Не могу придумать, как реализовать задание: написать код который будет получать список фильмов с адреса
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/movies.json
и выводить его в виде списка. Список разбит по страницам и на каждой странице отображается не более 10 записей. Соответственно каждая кнопка должна делать переход между страницами.Вот мой запрос:

```
    function fetchMovies() {
        return fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/movies.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
    }
    console.log(fetchMovies());
```

Как реализовать переход между страницами и отображение по 10 записей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если api не позволяет получить список фильмов постранично, а только полным списком из 3000 записей, то можно выкрутиться следующим образом:

1. Получаем один раз полный список.
2. Храним его внутри, а пользователю показываем постранично.

Вот примитивный пример реализации:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fetch pagination</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Film list:</h1>

    <section id="list"></section>

    <div class="pagination">
        <div>pagination:</div>
        <button id="prev">prev</button>
        <div id="page_number"></div>
        <button id="next">next</button>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
class App {
  constructor () {
    this.url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/movies.json' // api url
    this.movies = [] // массив для фильмов
    this.page = 0 // текущая страница
    this.limit = 20 // количество фильмов на странице

    this.elements = {
      list: document.getElementById('list'),
      pageNumber: document.getElementById('page_number'),
      prevButton: document.getElementById('prev'),
      nextButton: document.getElementById('next')
    }
  }

  // Внутренняя функция инициализации
  async init () {
    APP.movies = await fetch(APP.url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(() => [])
    console.log('Запросили один раз весь список фильмов, сохранили.')

    // Показываем первую страницу
    APP.showMovies()
    // Регистрируем клики по кнопкам навигации
    this._resisterListeners()
  }

  // Главная фукнция, отображает фильмы постранично
  showMovies (dir = 'next') {
    dir === 'next' ? APP.page++ : APP.page--
    APP.elements.list.innerHTML = ''
    APP.elements.pageNumber.textContent = APP.page
    const items = APP.movies.filter((i, j) => (j >= APP.limit * (APP.page - 1)) && (j < APP.limit * APP.page))
    console.log('Показываем страницу:', APP.page, ', элементы:', APP.limit * (APP.page - 1), APP.limit * APP.page)
    items.forEach(item => {
      const el = APP._createElement('div', 'movie')
      el.innerHTML = `<div class="title">${item.Title} (${item.IMDB_Rating})</div>`
      APP.elements.list.appendChild(el)
    })
  }

  // Вспомогательная функция по созданию элементов
  _createElement (tagName = 'div', className = 'movie') {
    const el = document.createElement(tagName)
    el.classList.add(className)
    return el
  }

  // Регистрация кликов по кнопкам
  _resisterListeners () {
    APP.elements.prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      APP.showMovies('prev')
    })
    APP.elements.nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      APP.showMovies('next')
    })
  }
}

// Инициализация кода по готовности страницы
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log('Инициализация APP')
  window.APP = new App()
  APP.init()
})
```

Вживую поиграться можно здесь:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkshi/bsyhocqj/